# How to specify path to libX11.6.dylib for XQuartz?

Tags: macos, x11, wine, xquartz, dynamic-library

I'm trying to run Wine with x11 driver (because some apps only work with x11 driver). I had installed XQuartz and it works and runs xterm.

However, when I run Wine, it outputs:

```
err:x11drv:process_attach failed to load libX11.6.dylib: dlopen(libX11.6.dylib, 266): image not found
err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly.
```

I have `libX11.6.dylib` in `/opt/X11/lib/libX11`. Specifying it with `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` or `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variables when running Wine does not have any effect.

Applications bundled into .app such as Inkscape also don't work, but Inkscape does not output any error messages, just windows don't appear.

What can I do so X11 apps will be able to use XQuartz?

Mac OS 10.12.4, XQuartz 2.7.11.

Comment: How are you specifying DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH or DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH? Also SIP will block these. Try using WineSkin for packagine Windows apps - it wraps Wine and the App and so advoids these issues

Comment: `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/X11/lib WINEPREFIX=… wine …`. Wineskin works, but seems that it bundles its own XQuartz.

Comment: Which file are you setting them in and how are you calling the wine app - ie so that we can repeat your setup

Comment: Created shell script: https://gist.github.com/kolen/b9b0a142a7e46fa9c97dbdde461823d5